# Client ID is 0 when updating entity model

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

***View***

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateClient", "Client")) {
```

***Controller***

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateClient(Client client)
{            
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {                
        bool ret = _clientRepository.UpdateClient(client);                
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    return View(client);
}
```

***Repository***

```
public bool UpdateClient(Client client)
{
    using (var context = new Entities()) {
        context.AttachTo("Clients",client);
        context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(client, EntityState.Modified);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    return true;
}
```

When I call the UpdateClient in the controller, the client ID is 0. How do I pass the ID I have updated?

Comment: When are you calling the controller's UpdateClient? Can you show that code?

Comment: I call the controller method(UpdateClient) from the view using a submit button.

Answer (score 0):

When you call your UpdateClient method from the client-side code (i.e, the browser), you need to make sure that the fields you want set are posted back to the receiving page.

For example, I often use jQuery and a simple ajax call to post data back to the server. The post needs to contain matching values for the Client object:

```
$.post("/controller/UpdateClient", {
        "clientId": 1,
        "otherProp1": "some value",
        "otherProp2": "some value 2"
    }, function (data) {

    }
};
```

In your case, you probably need to make sure you've got an `input` field that contains a field named after ClientId so that it gets posted to the server that way:

```
<input type="hidden" id="clientId" name="clientId" value="1" />
```

Additionally, you may find it useful to installer Fiddler2 and use it to watch the data actually being posted to the server. It's invaluable when dealing with this type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much info u gave us but your id can be 0 in 3 cases.
1. If you generate or input id on client side u just didn't post it properly. Missed hidden input, wrong variable name.
2. If you generate ur I'd in model constructor you should take in mind that there LL be default constructor called. Then it ll overwrite its properties with new values. Look at your id property is there something that can block or overwrite incoming value.
3. If u generate Id on database level  then you should know that data base don't return  id when creating new object.
Its a common problem, but I'm not very experienced in it(we generate id in business logic of application).

I'm sure ull track problem if u will have another look at your code.